# How to return the highest float value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, max

Below is my codes that I have tried, the check_keyword() method is to basically compare a string with a dictionary of words, if words matched, increment count and find the highest value in the dictionary:

Please focus on the codes where I have commented "find the maximum float value"

```
def check_keyword():
    new_dict = {}
    count_dict = {}
    new_list = []
    new_list2 = []
    count = 0
    with open(unknown.txt, "r") as fp:
        unknown_file = fp.read()
        print(unknown_file)
        # read key phases from text file as a dictionary
    df = pd.read_csv(key_phases.txt, sep='|')
    key_phases_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    for i in key_phases_dict:
        new_list = list(i.values())
        new_dict[new_list[0]] = new_list[1]

    for key in new_dict.keys():
        count_dict[key] = 0
        new_list2 = new_dict[key].split(",")
        new_dict[key] = new_list2
        for j in new_dict[key]:
            if j in unknown_file:
                print(j)
                count_dict[key] = count_dict[key] + 1
        count_dict[key] = float(count_dict[key] / len(new_list2))
    print(count_dict)
    # find the maximum float value 
    for k, v in count_dict.items():
        if v > count:
            highest_list = []
            result = k, v
            highest_list.append(result)
            count = v
        else:
            v == count
            result = k, v
            highest_list.append(result)

    return highest_list
```

The output of count_dic:

```
{2: 0.02666666666666667, 3: 0.08666666666666667, 4: 0.08666666666666667, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.04666666666666667, 7: 0.02, 8: 0.013333333333333334}
```

The problem encountered is that when I print highest_list it gives me (it does not shows me the highest value):

```
[(3, 0.08666666666666667), (4, 0.08666666666666667), (5, 0.0), (6, 0.04666666666666667), (7, 0.02), (8, 0.013333333333333334)]
```

Desired output to achieve:

```
[(3, 0.08666666666666667),(4, 0.08666666666666667)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just calculate the maximum value and then use a list comprehension:

```
d = {2: 0.02666666666666667, 3: 0.08666666666666667, 4: 0.08666666666666667, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.04666666666666667, 7: 0.02, 8: 0.013333333333333334}

maxval = max(d.values())
res = [(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v == maxval]

[(3, 0.08666666666666667), (4, 0.08666666666666667)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two ways to go about it.

One with `sorted` and a list comprehension:

```
d = {2: 0.02666666666666667, 3: 0.08666666666666667, 4: 0.08666666666666667, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.04666666666666667, 7: 0.02, 8: 0.013333333333333334}

sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
results = [item for item in sorted_items if item[1] == sorted_items[0][1]]

# output: [(3, 0.08666666666666667), (4, 0.08666666666666667)] #
```

And the other with `sorted` and `filter`:

```
d = {2: 0.02666666666666667, 3: 0.08666666666666667, 4: 0.08666666666666667, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.04666666666666667, 7: 0.02, 8: 0.013333333333333334}

sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
results = filter(lambda x: x[1] == sorted_items[0][1], sorted_items)

# output: [(3, 0.08666666666666667), (4, 0.08666666666666667)] #
```

With `sorted` you can use `key` to sort the items by the dictionary's values. `sorted_items` will give you:

```
[(3, 0.08666666666666667), (4, 0.08666666666666667), (6, 0.04666666666666667), (2, 0.02666666666666667), (7, 0.02), (8, 0.013333333333333334), (5, 0.0)]
```

Including `reverse` makes it so the first index of the results will be the highest value.

The 2nd line to get `results` is to filter the list if there are multiple indexes that have the same max value. With that it trims the list, and you end up with the final two values.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the code snippets to me... I dont really get the sort and filter codes? @Green call

Comment: @School I added some more explanations, hope that helps. If you are stumped on `lambda`, `map`, or `filter` try googling examples of them. Not trying to dodge the answer there, it's just that the top results will explain them better than I could.

Comment: Thanks @Green Cell I roughly get it, I will look up the lambda, map and filter for more understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
v == count
result = k, v
highest_list.append(result)
```

Try:

```
v = count
result = k, v
highest_list.append(result)
```

In other words, change `==` to `=`.